# analysing graph values

Tags: c++, linux, qt

hello every i want to ask that is there any way through which i can pick values from the plotted  graph and statistically analyze them using c++ programming and also the graph is moving graph (realtime graph)

thank u kindly help me
i am using c++ and linux and graph is plotted by using qwt and qt

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the sorts f analyses you're trying to do, since the answer will be highly dependent on what you want to look at in the data.

Comment: acctually i want to check that whether at any point my graph values become zero also my graph will be two way and i want to check that both side data is equal or not .some thing like that

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing doesn't look necessary for what you describe (if I got it well) and would be too costly. You simply need to create an observer system ; when a node value is changed, send a message with the new value. You'll only need to see if the value is zero. Add special events for the extreme nodes and check when their value is changed if they match.

Comment: sir kindly tell what do you meant by node?

Comment: Node : an element of a graph. In the case of a plotted graph, should be the different values you'll display. You'd have to give more detail about the way you implement the graph to get more informations. If your nodes are simple integer, just dispatch the event whenever any number is changed.